# What's a unique folder id?

Tags: python, directory, exchangelib

I'm setting folders in my dbms by identifying their folder.absolute name as a key.
In the case such name changes, a "different new" folder is detected by my python script.

How I can choose a real and universal (the same key through different calling script) ID of that folder, which means it doesn't change when the name changes?

thanks

Comment: What operating system are you on? the answer to this will depend on that.

Comment: python 3.11 over Mac os Ventura.

Comment: But, actually, i need a  key fixed all over the different OS...

Comment: Is the name of the folder changing asynchronously to when the database is updated?

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemId.Id` attribute of a folder in Exchange/EWS does not change just because the folder nam changes. In exchangelib, that would be `some_folder.id`.